# ServiceStack register error form CustomUserAuth in CredentialsAuthProvider

Tags: servicestack

searching the Internet I found many examples how to make your users table, everything works, check in on social networks, etc.

But I get problem when register's representative missions of RegistrationFeature.

It's a code and trace:

[image]

[image]

Thanks for help.

Comment: Can you include the class definiotion of LotoUserAuth and specify whether you're using the latest version of ServiceStack? Also you should only ether set [IncludeRegistrationService = true](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/7625198e0010ef85ceb8737d21bfbaf50c5e5e02/src/ServiceStack/AuthFeature.cs#L73) or register the RegistrationFeature plugin, not both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From v4.5.7+ that's [now on MyGet](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget) you'll be able to use the built-in `RegistrationFeature` in ServiceStack with Custom `IUserAuth` and `IUserAuthDetails` data models.

---

For ServiceStack versions v4.5.6 and prior:

If you want to use Custom UserAuth tables you need to either inherit the existing UserAuth table, e.g:

```
public class LotoUserAuth : UserAuth {}
```

Which will let you use the existing Register Service.

#### Using a Custom Register Service

If you only want to implement `IUserAuth` you need to register a Custom Register Service that populates your Custom UserAuth table instead, which you can do by inheriting `RegisterService<T>` with your Custom UserAuth type, e.g:

```
public class CustomRegisterService : RegisterService<CustomUserAuth> { }
```

and register it in your AppHost with:

```
this.RegisterService<CustomRegisterService>("/register");
```

When using a Custom RegisterService you need to disable your existing configuration that registers the built-in RegisterService by **removing these lines** from your AppHost:

```
//authFeature.IncludeRegistrationService = true;
//Plugins.Add(new RegistrationFeature());
```

Finally since you're using a Custom RegisterService you'll need to register the `RegistrationValidator` which the [RegistrationFeature would normally do](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/RegistrationFeature.cs#L21) in your AppHost with:

```
container.RegisterAs<RegistrationValidator, IValidator<Register>>();
```

#### AppHost Configuration Issues

Other problems with your AppHost is that you should register your Custom `OrmLiteAuthRepository` against the `IAuthRepository` interface:

```
container.Register<IAuthRepository>(c => 
    new OrmLiteAuthRepository<LotoUserAuth, UserAuthDetails>(
        c.Resolve<IDbConnectionFactory>()));
```

Then if you'll need to create the Schema with:

```
container.Resolve<IAuthRepository>().InitSchema();
```

Comment: hi, tahanks a lot, it helped: 

`this.RegisterService<CustomRegisterService>("/register");            this.RegisterAs<RegistrationValidator, IValidator<Register>>();`

Comment: @MherArsh shouldn't need to register manually if `CustomRegisterService` is in your same ServiceInterface Assembly which your AppHost is initialized to look at. But yeah you would need to manually register it in order to register the service at `/register`.